# TFS Merge missing out few files during merge

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I am facing the below scenario while merging in TFS. Not sure if i am using the correct approach.

I have a Main from which a Dev is branched out. Several changes have been made in Dev and around 10 files modified in Main. I want to merge Dev over Main, the 10 files which i modified in Main must be overwritten with the one in Dev, along with the other changes. But when i merge, the 10 files are not getting afftected in Main it is just showing the other files. Is this how merge will work?

When i try to merge Main over Dev the files created in Dev are waiting to be deleted in Pending changes. How is this merge Possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the changes in MAIN (instead of merging them with DEV), then just rollback the changesets in MAIN you don't want, then merge DEV into MAIN.